# Programmatically Add User to Report Server (SSRS 2005)

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I would like to be able to programatically add a user to the report server by creating some stored procedure that accepts user_id and does inserts into ReportServer..Users and other associated tables. I am having trouble doing this (especially the column ReportServer..Users.Sid).

Has anyone been able to accomplish this in the past?

The end goal would be to have a script on my local PC that connects via osql to add users to the database so they can ad-hoc query and also add them to the report server so they can have access to the reports website. I have gotten the database access working...that was fairly easy. Having problems with report server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't add users to RS this way. It's a seriously bad idea.

[Why not just add "Everyone" into the "Browser" role?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156014%28SQL.90%29.aspx) This is effectively what you are doing...