# Add user to reporting as Browser or ContentManager

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am trying find how to add some users to our deployed reports folder. Currently we have an application what has a routine where our rdl files are deployed automatically what is working pretty well. Now as a new requirement we need to add some users to this reports folder.
I see someone was looking for something similar, except that he wanted using sql logic..

[Programmatically Add User to Report Server (SSRS 2005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346818/programmatically-add-user-to-report-server-ssrs-2005)

So my question is: is there some way to add user using .net framework?

Also I have found this related with associate permission to a specific item: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.setpolicies.aspx

Answer (score 0):

IF someone needs something similar I leave what is working for me:

```
Public Sub AddUserToRoleOnFolder(userName As string, role As String, reportFolderName As String) 

    dim allPoliciesInReportFolder =  ReportingService.GetPolicies("/" & reportFolderName,False).ToList()
    dim policiesForCurrentUser  = allPoliciesInReportFolder.FirstOrDefault(Function (f) f.GroupUserName =userName)
    dim policyExists = policiesForCurrentUser IsNot Nothing
    try
        If  policyExists then
            AddNewRoleToPolicy( policiesForCurrentUser, role)
        else
            AddNewPolicy(userName, role, allPoliciesInReportFolder)
        End If
        ReportingService.SetPolicies("/" & reportFolderName,allPoliciesInReportFolder.ToArray())
    Catch ex As SoapException
        Throw New AuthenticationException($"Insufficient permissions for to assign roles in RS for {Configuration.Domain}\{Configuration.Username}. User must be a member of the Local Administrator Group on the RS server.", ex)
    End Try


End Sub

Private Sub AddNewPolicy(userName As String, role As String, ByRef  allPoliciesInReportFolder As List( of Policy)  )
    Dim policy As New Policy()
    policy.GroupUserName = userName
    policy.Roles = ReportingService.ListRoles(SecurityScopeEnum.All).Where(Function(r) r.Name = role).ToArray()
    allPoliciesInReportFolder.Add(policy)
End Sub

Private Sub AddNewRoleToPolicy(byref policiesForCurrentUser As Policy, roleName As String)
    if  Not policiesForCurrentUser.Roles.Where(function(r) r.Name=roleName).Any() Then
        dim role as Role=ReportingService.ListRoles(SecurityScopeEnum.All).Where(Function(r) r.Name = roleName).FirstOrDefault()
        dim roles = policiesForCurrentUser.Roles.ToList()
        roles.Add(role)
        policiesForCurrentUser.Roles= roles.ToArray()
    End If
End Sub
```